# SUM in Excel VBA is not working for 1 workbook

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following code to create a summary of commissions payments from several Excel workbooks.

The code works as planned, except the sum isn't working for just one workbook.

I've tried various options for the sum statement, but none have resolved the problem.  Summing within the workbook works fine.

```
Sub CommissionsCompile()

Dim d As Variant, dIndex As Long
Dim numFiles As Long, NBFiles As Long
Dim path As String
Dim filename As String
Dim bonus As Double


With Application
    .DisplayAlerts = False
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .EnableEvents = False
End With

districts = Worksheets("Lookups").Range(district).Value

For Each d In districts
    'The folder containing the files to be recap'd
    myPath = fpath & d

    'Finds the name of the first file of type .* in the current directory
    CurrentFileName = Dir(myPath & "\*")

    'Create a workbook for the recap report
    Set Master = ThisWorkbook

    Do While CurrentFileName <> ""
        Workbooks.Open filename:=myPath & "\" & CurrentFileName, UpdateLinks:=0
        Set sourceBook = Workbooks(CurrentFileName)
        On Error GoTo markFile
        Set sourceData = sourceBook.Worksheets(period)
        On Error GoTo 0

        With sourceData
            .Unprotect "analyst"
            If (.AutoFilterMode And .FilterMode) Or .FilterMode Then
                .ShowAllData
            End If
            .Range("z21:z21").Copy
            bonus = [sum(z22:z23)]
        End With
        currentrow = Workbooks(ThisWorkbook.Name).Worksheets("Commissions").UsedRange.Rows.Count
        With Master.Worksheets("Commissions").Range("E" & currentrow + 1)
            .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues
          Master.Worksheets("Commissions").Range("F" & currentrow + 1) = bonus
        End With



        Application.CutCopyMode = False

        endrow = Workbooks(ThisWorkbook.Name).Worksheets("Commissions").UsedRange.Rows.Count

        Master.Worksheets("Commissions").Range("A" & currentrow + 1 & ":A" & endrow).Value = sourceData.Range("C1")
        Master.Worksheets("Commissions").Range("B" & currentrow + 1 & ":B" & endrow).Value = sourceData.Range("C2")
        Master.Worksheets("Commissions").Range("C" & currentrow + 1 & ":C" & endrow).Value = sourceData.Range("C3")
        Master.Worksheets("Commissions").Range("D" & currentrow + 1 & ":D" & endrow).Value = sourceData.Range("C5")


nextItem:
        sourceBook.Close savechanges:=False
        'Calling DIR w/o argument finds the next .xlsx file within the current directory.
        CurrentFileName = Dir()

    Loop
Next d

With Application
    .DisplayAlerts = True
    .ScreenUpdating = True
    .EnableEvents = True
End With

Exit Sub
```

Comment: *"isn't working"* is no helpful error description. Instead please tell which error you get and in which line. • Try worksheet function sum and specify a sheet for the range `bonus = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(Worksheets("SheetName").Range("z22:z23"))`

Comment: Have you tried stepping through your code? You can use the Locals window to watch the values of all the variables; make sure all the variables have the values you expect for the workbook that isn't working. Is there anything different about that particular workbook? Can you create a new workbook with the same data and see if that one works?

Comment: Are z22:z23 text, text that looks like numbers or real numbers on the rogue worksheet?